# Want to hide a Custom field which is holding a reference getting used in a trigger

Tags: custom-field

I have got 3 objects
1)Change
2)Requirement
3)CR-Req(junction between Change and Requirement)

now we have a related list of CR-Req under Change object which is having a custom button named "New Requirement".

On clicking this button we are redirected to a Requirement page having the Salesforce ID of the Change object populated in a custom field named check(this field is just used for holding the ID value, because I am using this 18 digit IDs in a trigger). The trigger creates a record of Requirement under the CR-Req related list of Change page.

My Requirement is I dont want this Check field to be shown to anybody but the trigger should work.

However what I am finding is if I am making the FLS hidden or keeping the field hidden from page layout, the trigger is unable to get the ID, thus not populating a new record under Change page.

Any ideas how I can keep the check field hidden as well as make the trigger work?

Comment: Are you sure?? Removing the field fro the page layout should have absolutely no effect on the inner workings or permissions of the system. And as long as you use `without sharing` on any trigger helper methods, the trigger will ignore FLS.

Comment: The trigger won't see it because the page won't accept it if it's hidden. I'm afraid the only real solution here is Visualforce.